# Raphael canvas (background) onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, dom-events, raphael

I have been working with Raphael to create drag and drop shapes on a canvas. I do this using the `.drag()` function (supplied in the Raphael framework) along with my event functions. I have no issues doing this.

I also have a function that creates a new shape `onDblClick`, the problem is, I can only attach the event to a shapes, or other elements I create.

Adding events to a shape works like so:

```
  R = Raphael("canvas", "100%", "100%"),
  R.rect(100, 100, 25, 50).attr({fill: fillColor}).dblclick(myDblClick);
```

Using the same principle on the canvas **doesn't work**:

```
  R = Raphael("canvas", "100%", "100%"),
  R.dblclick(myDblClick);
```

Does anybody know a way to attach click events to the canvas, i.e. I can click anywhere in the div (excluding shapes) and the event will be triggered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would just attach the regular click event (with vanilla javascript, or whatever js framework you are using) to the the canvas node (or the parent node that contains the #canvas element).

With jquery:

```
//Bound to canvas
$('#canvas').bind('dblclick', myDblClick);
//Bound to parent
$('#canvas').parent().bind('dblclick', myDblClick);
```

Otherwise, if you are dead-set on using Raphael events, you could draw a rectangle over the entire canvas, and capture click events on that. but that seems like a lot of overhead.

Comment: The issue with this is that the event is still called if a shape is clicked on. I only want the background to be applicable to this event.

Comment: Inside myDblClick, inspect the event.originalTarget and if it is node a "rect" etc. then fire a custom event. $('#canvas').trigger('dblclick.raphDblClick', {origEvent:event});. Something along those lines should work

Comment: Usually you move the `paper` around, so `paper.canvas` should also work.

Answer (score 19):

As the accepted answer didn't work for me (though it did get me on the right track) I thought I would post how I solved it in case there is anybody else in my position...

```
//Create paper element from canvas DIV
var canvas = $("#Canvas");
paper = Raphael("Canvas", canvas.width(), canvas.height());

//Register Event
$("#Canvas").click(CanvasClick);

//Event Handler
function CanvasClick(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName == "svg")
    {
       //This will only occur if the actual canvas area is clicked, not any other drawn elements
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

musefans solution with IE compatiblity. Thanks

```
//Create paper element from canvas DIV
var canvas = $("#Canvas");
paper = Raphael("Canvas", canvas.width(), canvas.height());

$("#canvas").click(canvasClick);

canvasClick: function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName == "svg" || e.target.nodeName == "DIV" )

},
```